# How do I handle an exception that's being thrown when using SpreadsheetApp.openById()

Tags: exception, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm very new to coding of any kind and search as I might I wasn't able to find a solution for this exception:

> Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp. (line 16)

The script I've written copies each file from a list of file IDs, pastes entire contents as values into the copied files.

What I've already done is check if there was an authorisation required in oauthScope in my appscript.json and I think I've given sufficient authorisation (spreadsheet and drive). I don't get any other permission prompts.

Any help or suggestions will be great (generally for what I've written, but importantly for the exception)

This is the script:

```
function copyPasteValues()
{
  //Define destination archive folder
  var Destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");

  //Open correct sheet in the Archiving Center file and get ID range
  var AllFileID_ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID_2"); *------- no error on this one*
  var AllFileID_sheet = AllFileID_ss.getSheetByName("Sheets_to_be_archived");
  var FileID = AllFileID_sheet.getRange("B2:B10").getValues();

  //Select the correct file to archive and create a copy
  for (var i=0; i<FileID.length;i++)
  {
    if (FileID != "-")
    {
      var archfile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(FileID[i]); *------------ exception being thrown here (line 16)*
      var archcopy = DriveApp.getFileById(FileID[i]).makeCopy("Archive "+archfile.getName(), Destination);
      var copyId = archcopy.getId();
      var sheetNumber = archfile.getSheets().length;

      //Select correct sheets in copy, and paste values
      for (var j=0; j<sheetNumber;j++)
      {
        var values = archfile.getSheets()[j].getDataRange().getValues();
        SpreadsheetApp.openById(copyId).getSheets()[j].getRange(archfile.getSheets()[j].getDataRange().getA1Notation()).setValues(values);
      }    
    }
  }

  Browser.msgBox("Archiving is done");
}
```

P.S. The script runs fine otherwise and carries out the copy and archive despite the exception, but the last line which is a `msgBox` does not display the message. I do not know why.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Plese, leave pleasantries out of the question for the future (although they are most welcome in comments if they are constructive). `FileID` is a matrix of values since this is what `getValues()` returns. Therefore, it is not enough to access the row via `[i]`, you have to access the column afterwards. Currently, you try to pass an array of values to `openById`

Comment: As a tip try using logs for debugging. You have the [Logger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger) class. And also the Stack Driver log.

Comment: @Aerials - good tip Just a note that using `Logger` class is now nearly useless, use `console` instead. Benefit - more browser-compatible code. `Logger` since it got piped to Stackdriver loads logs way too slow to be really useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openbyidid), `openById(id)` method signature expects a string as a parameter. Your `FileID` variable holds an array of arrays of values returned by the `getValues()` method call (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)), hence accessing an item from it by index `[i]` returns an array, and not the value.

The condition `FileID != "-"` is always evaluated to `true` in your script, since you are doing a [strict comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Identity) that checks for inequality in your case. It returns `true` as soon a type mismatch happens: `"object" !== "string"`.

```js
const whatGetValuesReturns = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
];

const whatOpenByIdExpects = "string";

for(var i = 0; i < whatGetValuesReturns.length; i++) {
  const whatEachIterationOfLoopGets = whatGetValuesReturns[i];
  
  const typeOfWhatIsExtracted = typeof whatEachIterationOfLoopGets;
  
  console.log(
  `Expected ${whatOpenByIdExpects}, 
got ${typeOfWhatIsExtracted} with values:
${whatEachIterationOfLoopGets.join(" ")}`
  );
  
}
```

---

Based on the discussion, I need to clarify that when you limit `getRange()` to a single column (off-note: `B:B` would be a column reference, `B2:B10` is a range of cells) it still returns a [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) instance, which in turn has a `getValues()` method defined that always returns a matrix of values:

```js
const singleColumn = [
  [1],
  [2],
  [3],
  [4]
];

for(const row of singleColumn) {
  const value = row[0]; //<-- since we have only one, first index is used
  console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your corrections Oleg. Might be a stupid one but, question: 
I've written: var FileID = AllFileID_sheet.getRange("B2:B10").getValues();

I've specified the column under getRange as B2:B10. Doesn't that mean getValues will get me the rows and I'm accessing the value via [i]?


Also, I have dashes (' - ') in my data file and i don't want the script to proceed when it encounters a dash.  Hence the if FileID != "-". Is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: @NarenSuri - you should read up on [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) docs - as said, it returns an in-memory array of arrays of values, it has nothing to do with "getting the rows" - you see, when you access the value using the index, you go only one level in depth. If an array is multi-level, you have to access each one individually

Comment: re:dashes - there is nothing wrong with the condition, the problem you have is with the `FileID` variable. You expect it to contain a list of values from columns, but in reality it contains a list of rows that in turn contain a list of values

Comment: I see you have an assumption that limiting the range to a column would get you only the column, but that's not how programs work - they are very stupid. You told the script to get you a list rows where each row is a list (array) with only one item, and that's what it returned

Comment: Ah I see what I did there. You caught my assumption.
Thanks very much, I did go through what getValues() does but did not understand exactly how it worked as much as I do now. I'm not sure what the etiquette is, but can i leave this post open for any further questions I may have after re-exploring this?

Comment: @NarenSuri No worries - I just meant is that you should carefully examine docs on what value types are returned, even a slightest mismatch can ruin the whole app. Re:leave open - if this is a substantially new change - ask another question (you can leave a link to this one there if you want to give others more context), if it fits the current scope - feel free to update (but not replace) the question. But try to find out if the question is not a duplicate first - this is a huge repository, and the question is likely to be closed and linked to another one that has a solution

Comment: Note that method signatures don't usually change, as a general rule, if a method call returns a string, it will always return a string. That's not always the case, but I wouldn't recommend doing that.

Answer (score 0):

As you @Oleg Valter rightly pointed out, I had tried to pass what I thought would be a string value, but was actually an array, into openbyID(id). Your comment below clarified it.

> I see you have an assumption that limiting the range to a column would get you only the column, but that's not how programs work - they are very stupid. You told the script to get you a list rows where each row is a list (array) with only one item, and that's what it returned

I modified this part of the script as below and it worked:

```
var AllFileID = AllFileID_sheet.getRange("B2:B10").getValues();

  //Select the correct file to archive and create a copy
  for (var i=0; i<AllFileID.length;i++)
  {
    var FileID = AllFileID[i][0] *----this is the change to pick out the value from the array*
    if (FileID != "-")
    {
      var archfile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(FileID); *---works!*
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad you resolved it! Please, edit the response part out of the answer when you can (leave the citation if you want as most comments are deleted after a while) or this might be closed as "not an answer". Answers as response are frowned upon on SO, but as you added modified code and an explanation, you should be fine, just remember that SO is a bit different from forums (btw, your answer, as you are new user, gets into a review queue to be peer-reviewed). Once again - welcome to SO, it is nice to see newcomers actually want to understand both the issue at hand and the rules of the site

Comment: Well the response I got from you was amazingly quick and helpful! SO enabled it and I didn't want to be selfish by not following protocols if any. Also, I thought the way to end my question is by posting the answer or my understanding myself! I know better now, Thanks again Oleg

Comment: Naren, thanks for the feedback - you'll likely have the same experience overall if you follow the (admittedly, there might be a lot of nuances) rules of SO. Don't worry about referencing people too much - we are all here to help. You are correct about posting an answer on your understanding - it is encouraged and thanks for doing so - someone might benefit from seeing the implementation instead of reading through reasoning why it happened - so keep it up (just remeber that self-answers tend to get a bit more scrutiny from peers)!